# video insertion in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, video, store

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO GAME values (3, 'Termonator2',LOAD_FILE("C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos\\Sample Video\\test.wmv"));
```

When I run this query, I get 'row inserted successfully' with no error but I can't see video link or any thing in video column Y - I don't understand that.

Whereas I can see '3`and`Termonator2`in specified columns - perhaps *MySQL* doesn't support`.wmv`?

If no, then which extensions could I use? (sorry in advance for may be bit stupid question I'm new to all this business of trying to store videos links in MySQL database, so thanks in advance :)

Comment: [storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748)

Comment: Exactly. Store **file paths** in the database, leave the actual data in the **file system**. That's what it's best for.

Comment: You've got to learn how to write good questions if you are going to post in this forum!  You know, proper grammar, formatting, etc.  I've cleaned it up this time.

Comment: AS GBM says, write your questions properly. Then someone might be able to/ want to read them. **Same applies for your code.** Write clear & understandable, so you & other people can follow.

Comment: @BGM,@Thomas i will take care of this next time ,i posted here for the first time i think i got it now thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

its probably because of the quote " signs

try using this method instead

```
$address='LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Video\test.wmv")';// assuming u are using php

INSERT INTO GAME values (3, 'Termonator2',$address);
```

Comment: Basically i want to embed a *media player* on my web age n link it with  *MySQL* i am currently working in _adobe flash media player_ is it a good choice? or i should go for something else please guide me a little bit so i can choose the better path thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion,but i am getting this ERROR after i pasted your suggested code – *ERROR SQL query*: `$address = 'LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\Public\Videos\SampleVideo\test.wmv")';`        MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'$address='LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Video\test.wmv")''` at line 1

Comment: @MaryamKhan there was probably one error in my code, I have edited it , so please try using this correct code.Hope it works for you

Comment: No its still giving exactly the same error :( i cannot figure out what change you made in the CODE, anyways please guide me with *mySQL* database i should choose which stuff for developing my media player